# Sitecore Content Editor HTML Code Formatting

Tags: sitecore

Have recently started working with Sitecore 6.2.

Is there a way to preserve code formatting inside of the "HTML" editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Ursino has blogged about this here: http://firebreaksice.com/prevent-sitecore-content-editor-from-stripping-script-tags/

I think that has all the info you need.